# pass link text to next page

Tags: php, html, json, form-submit

For my actual web-project, I made a tagcloud. When I click on a tag, it should be passed to the page `showRecipesFromTags.php`.

```
<form name="tagform" id="tagform" method="get" action="/showRecipesFromTags.php">
<?php
include('php/getRandomTags.php');
$tagsarr = json_decode($return4634, true);

foreach ($tagsarr['Data']['Tag'] as $key => $tag11) {   
echo '<a id="seastags" href="#" onclick="document.tagform.submit()"><font size="' . rand(1,4) .'">' . $tag11['Tag_name'] . '</font> <br/></a> ';
}
?>
</form>
```

It can already go to this page by clicking on the href, but what I need is to pass the id of the clicked tag. The name of the tag is called `Tag_name`. The name is shown but I don´t know how the pass the id to the next site. The id is in my JSON array and is called `Tag_id`.

How can I manage this?

Comment: what about using url query like `?tagID=$tid` and using `$_GET['tagID']` in your `showRecipesFromTags.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you even need a form? Just use plain links.
Try using this in the `foreach` loop:

`echo '<a id="seastags" href="/showRecipesFromTags.php?tagId=' .$tag11['Tag_id'] . '"><font size="' . rand(1,4) .'">' . $tag11['Tag_name'] . '</font> <br/></a> ';`

Answer (score 1):

Your choice are:

- use a hidden field
- put it in the URL
- use a cookie